# When can a template method use a function defined later, without forward declaration?

Tags: c++, qt, templates

I am writing a simple logger class similar to QDebug, which has a template method that save data into QStringList. The code is here:

```
#include <QtCore/QString>
#include <QtCore/QStringList>
#include <QtCore/QTextStream>

class Logger
{
    public:
        Logger();

        ~Logger();

        template <typename V>
        Logger &operator<<(V const &value);

    private:
        QStringList msg;
};

inline Logger::Logger():
    msg(QString("INFO:"))
{}

inline Logger::~Logger()
{
    QTextStream out(stderr);
    out << msg.join("");
}

template <typename V>
inline Logger &Logger::operator<<(V const &value)
{
    msg << log(value);
    return *this;
}

inline QString log(QString const &value)
{
    return value;
}

inline QString log(int const (&value)[20])
{
    return QString("Array");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Logger c;
    int a[20] = {};
    c << QString("test") << a;

    return 0;
}
```

However, this doesn't compile with GCC 4.8.3.

```
$ g++ -I/usr/include/qt4 -L/usr/lib64/qt4 -lQtCore -o test2 test2.cpp
test2.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Logger& Logger::operator<<(const V&) [with V = int [20]]’:
test2.cpp:50:29:   required from here
test2.cpp:32:21: error: ‘log’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
     msg << log(value);
                     ^
test2.cpp:41:16: note: ‘QString log(const int (&)[20])’ declared here, later in the translation unit
 inline QString log(int const (&value)[20])
```

Indeed, if I move `inline QString log(int const (&value)[20])` to the beginning or put a forward declaration, it compiles and works. But what confuses me is that `inline QString log(QString const &value)` works without any problem:

```
$ ./test2
INFO:testArray
```

I notice that QHash relies on qHash function, which is similar in this case. QHash works pretty fine with user-defined key classes (except arrays, which can't be a function return type).

Why do they behave differently? What did I miss here?

Thank you for your help.

BTW: Would you please tell me what would be good keywords for this question. I've tried combinations of "specialiation" "template" "forward declaration" "QHash" and "user-defined types", but they don't work.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "inline QString log(QString const &value) works without any problem." There are no calls to that overload of `log` in this code.

Comment: I'm too tired to think, but it's probably related to http://cppquiz.org/quiz/question/130

Comment: @chris, Thank you for that quiz. Please correct me: `msg << log(value)` is dependent, which will be postpone after the type is known. And the type is known at `c << QString("test") << a;` , which is after the definition of `inline QString log(int const (&value)[20])`.

Comment: @Matt McNabb: I just add the result of the working program. As it outputs `test`, which is from `QString("test")`, I think it is actually called.

Comment: @nocte107 where is the code for the working program?

Comment: @MattMcNabb, Move the definition of `inline QString log(int const (&value)[20])` to the beginning, before the class definition.

Comment: @nocte107 I'm not sure what you don't understand then:  `log` cannot be called before it is declared, and it can be called after it is declared

Comment: @MattMcNabb: The question is in the original code, both functions are defined after the template method definition, before main function. But `c << QString("test")` works and `<< a` doesn't compile. At the template method definition, both functions are unknown. In the main function, both functions are defined. Why do they behave differently?

Comment: Do you mean the original code but with the modification that `c << QString("test") << a;` is replaced by `c << QString("test");` ?  If so, that fails to compile for me (g++ 4.8.3) with the same error message as the original

Comment: @MattMcNabb. No, what I mean is by following the error message provided above, moving`inline QString log(int const (&value)[20]) { return QString("Array"); }` to the beginning, after `#include`.

Comment: @nocte107 Do you mean the original code but only with the change that `inline QString log(int const (&value)[20]) { return QString("Array"); }` is moved to the beginning?  If so, `c << a;` compiles because `log` which accepts `a` is visible, and `c << QString("test");` fails to compile, because the `log` which accepts `QString` is not visible. `c << QString("test") << a;` also fails to compile for the same reason.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, No. If I move the definition, it compiles without problem with both overloading. Igor Tandetnik gives out the reason.

Comment: my results are as stated, so if you have accurately described the code, one of us has a compiler bug.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, I see. It is quite annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name `log` is looked up twice. At the point of template definition, ordinary lookup is performed. It doesn't find anything, since `log` is not declared at this point.

Then, at the point of instantiation, only argument-dependent lookup is performed. When the parameter is of type `QString`, the global namespace is searched since `QString` is declared there, and so `log(QString)` is found. But the type `int[]` doesn't have any associated namespaces, so argument-dependent lookup has nothing to search and finds nothing. Hence the error.

Comment: Thank you. Does that mean, if I want to use this class, I have define `log` for all fundamental types that have no associated namespaces? Is it possible I can enumerate all those types?

Comment: Well, you have to define `log` for every type you plan to call it with.  Whether the parameter is of a fundamental type or otherwise only determines whether you need a declaration (or definition) before use - but you need a definition *somewhere* either way.

Comment: @IgorTandetnic: I understand that. For custom types, I can have a relaxed position to define. For fundamental types, I need to define before the template. I checked http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1.aspx , and noticed that it is actually not that many types. But combining with arrays and so on can be really annoying. Maybe I should write a template class for that logging function. Thanks again.